# Div's position bothering another divs so I can't click on them

Tags: html, css

Probably one noob question, but I can't understand positioning in css very good. Yesterday I had a problem with background and drop-down menu, so I decided to start again from scratch. The problem persists.

My h1 couldn't be in position I wanted so I made its position:relative and then I could move it, but because of that I can't click on my drop-down menu or even on logo. Just half of it.

HTML:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style2.css"  />
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="stajl">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Home Page </a></li><li>
 <a href="#">Services <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
 <ul><li>
 <a href="#">Trades </a></li><li>
 <a href="#">Exchanges </a></li><li>
 <a href="#">Business to Business </a></li>
 </ul>
 <li><a href="#">About </a></li><li>
 <a href="#">Contact </a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="img">
 <a href="#"><img src="pfslogo2.png" /> </a>
 </div>
 <div id="header">
 <h1>We're here to help! </h1>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
overflow-y: scroll;}
#stajl ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
float: right;

}
#stajl ul li:hover a{
background-color: #d7e6fa;
}

#stajl ul li {
display: inline-block;

}

#stajl ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 15px;
color: white;
background-color: #0099cc;

}

#stajl ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -105px;
}
#stajl ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

#stajl ul ul li {
display: block;
color: white;
width: 352px;

}
#stajl ul li li a:hover {
color: cyan;
}
.arrow {
font-size: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#img img {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
top: 0;
left:0;
}
#header h1 {
padding: 0;
margin:0;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
top: -40px;
left: -60px;
color: #0099cc;
}
```

Codepen created by Dorvalla for my problem: codepen.io/anon/pen/VeXyRY

Any advice will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Might this be related to the fact `h1` is rendered with a initial margin top/bottom ?

Comment: I added a width of 400px and changed left to 100px and it works fine for me

Comment: Created a codepen for your problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeXyRY

Comment: Might be, but if I don't put top: -40px, I can't put it where I want + I tried to delete that top:-40px; now and drops few lines down and then I am able to click on my drop-down menu, but I am not able to click on "trades" in drop-down. I can't click on anything that is in the same line as h1.

Thanks for response though! :D

Comment: I checked your codepen. It doens't work :) You can just click on very top of drop-down menu items, you can't click on middle of it.

Comment: I created it for the problem, i have no solution just of yet :)

Comment: When I delete position:relative I can't put my h1 on the very top, where I want it to be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The H1 is Blocking the Cursor, you need to set the H1 to be a bit shorter:

```
#header {
  text-align:center;
}
#header h1 {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/niorad/pen/EPEQxJ

Comment: It also worked! What's difference between it and z-index: -1; ? Thanks though!

Comment: Both should work. With this solution, the element goes out of the way on the X-Axis, with Z-Index, the element goes out of the way on the Z-Axis ("into" the page). I prefer it over z-index because I'm not a fan of keeping track of all the index-numbers.

Comment: I just played with both of them and got a same conclusion because z-index keeps block all over the page which isn't that good. 
Is it good that I used position:relative in #header h1 ? I mean, I couldn't move my h1 without it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the z-index of your menu higher than that of the div.

Comment: All I did is z-index: -1; to #header h1 {} and it worked! 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Put a `z-index: -1;` on your h1, then your navigation will work again.

Comment: I did it! It worked but only with z-index: -1. When I tried to put z-index:2; to my navigation and z-index:1; to my h1 it didn't work! Thanks